Transform a calendar of tasks (table) into an actionable monthly task list
My questions:
Working in Google Sheets, I want to get a vertical list of tasks organised by year and month with the matching due date, each task in their own cell.

How can I do this?
What would be the best strategy to tackle this?

My data
My data source is a table with dates on two header rows (year on row 3 and months on row 4), a column (B) with tasks; in the table, there are a series of X that marks when the tasks should be performed. A bit like this:



…
B
...
H
I
J
K
…
BO





.

2024




← years; merged cells



.

J
F
M
A
M
← months



task 1

X



X




task 2



X

X




task 3




X





Data sample: Obviously there are many more tasks and a few more years https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bfLeXJj7bRzqalWBMt5dzkqlwheSBaksX1BIef9FPOE/
In a distinct sheet/tab I'm trying to write a formula to get a vertical list of tasks organised by year and month with the matching due date. I've been banging my head alone, and then with Claude-3 and Chat-gpt, but got nowhere really working. Often getting into mismatching range size.
The ideal output would be:



Year
Months
Tasks
extra column
for manual
data entry




2024
J
Task 1





2024
M
Task 2





2024
A
Task 3





2024
M
Task 1





2024
M
Task 2






NB there is also an "ideal output" tab on the spreadsheet I shared above.
Extra background:
this is the maintenance task list for the building we live in; it has been submitted by architects who ran the survey and I have now to organise what to do and when; and run a log book so we can check which task has been completed or not, by who, when, and any related notes...
What I tried and the closest I got:

=FLATTEN(FILTER('Calendrier 2024-2028'!$B5:$B78, 'Calendrier 2024-2028'!H5:H78="X")) → but this needs repeating for each month columns

The second one seems promising (even though it's not very DRY), but I can't get the matching dates for each tasks within a second column…
=FLATTEN(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA({FILTER('Calendrier 2024-2028'!$B4:$B78, 'Calendrier 2024-2028'!H4:H78="X");
                             FILTER('Calendrier 2024-2028'!$B4:$B78, 'Calendrier 2024-2028'!I4:I78="X");
                             FILTER('Calendrier 2024-2028'!$B4:$B78, 'Calendrier 2024-2028'!J4:J78="X");
                             FILTER('Calendrier 2024-2028'!$B4:$B78, 'Calendrier 2024-2028'!K4:K78="X");
                             FILTER('Calendrier 2024-2028'!$B4:$B78, 'Calendrier 2024-2028'!L4:L78="X");
                             FILTER('Calendrier 2024-2028'!$B4:$B78, 'Calendrier 2024-2028'!M4:M78="X");
                             FILTER('Calendrier 2024-2028'!$B4:$B78, 'Calendrier 2024-2028'!N4:N78="X");
                             FILTER('Calendrier 2024-2028'!$B4:$B78, 'Calendrier 2024-2028'!O4:O78="X");
                             FILTER('Calendrier 2024-2028'!$B4:$B78, 'Calendrier 2024-2028'!P4:P78="X");
                             FILTER('Calendrier 2024-2028'!$B4:$B78, 'Calendrier 2024-2028'!Q4:Q78="X")
}),
               "select Col1 where Col1 is not null"))



=Concatenate(CHAR(9744), JOIN(Concatenate(CHAR(10),CHAR(9744)),FILTER('Calendrier 2024-2028'!$B$5:$B$80,'Calendrier 2024-2028'!H$5:H$80="X"))) → is what I use currently but the tasks got assembled per month and don't have their own cell


Any help in getting this huge table into a summarised list of action points would be super appreciated :) thank you for reading this far!

It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

I submitted a request and will update asap; thanks for suggesting this!

not sure how the anonymous blank sheet I supposed to work; nobody came back to me ‍♂️ so I made a sample data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bfLeXJj7bRzqalWBMt5dzkqlwheSBaksX1BIef9FPOE/edit?usp=sharing

Before I workout a formula, just wanted to let you know that it seems like you plan to add some manual data(checkbox, data done, notes etc.,) aside the formula output. that seldom works since the formula output is dynamic in nature and manual data you'll be adding is always static; in simpler terms it means that manual data you intend to add will always stay in the same rows whilst the formula output data will be shuffling up and down based on changes happening in the source data sheet!

Usually you'll receive an email (in couple of minutes to the email address you submitted in the form) with a shared link to the anon sheet. Maybe you could also look into spam folder just in case...

hey @rockinfreakshow thanks for the notice on static vs dynamic data; I'm well aware of the risks this represents but thanks nonetheless for the reminder/warning!

also I apologise for the weird formatting of my second table in md; since I added the data sample url (that contains also an ideal output model) the markdown table wont display correctly (despite it rendering perfectly well in the question-editing preview screen). → probably a bug report for the meta stack? ← if any admin reads this

as a mitigation for the risk on static vs dynamic data, for anyone visiting this later: I made a protected sheet that dynamically aggregates all the task (cf the accepted solution below), and there is an extra one serving as a log book, in which data have been manually copy-pasted with the special paste (values only). TBH, this is far from being idiot proof—but this is a good enough safe guard for my use.


You may try:
=let(Σ,tocol(,1),data,'source calendar'!H2:AE27,
 reduce(Σ,sequence(columns(data)),lambda(a,c,ifna(vstack(a,hstack(chooserows(choosecols(data,c),1),chooserows(choosecols(data,c),2),filter('source calendar'!B4:B27,chooserows(choosecols(data,c),sequence(rows(data)-2,1,3))="X")))))))



perfect; I'm still unsure what now how; but I will study this carefully!
thank you!
